# What configuration of output neurons to use for detecting bias

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, softmax

I am trying to make a deep learning model that detects political bias in media articles for my local community. There are two political parties here and I have a dataset of biased articles from both. I do not have a dataset of unbiased articles.

Can I implement a neural network with 2 output neurons for each party, and if the accuracy of the prediction is under some value (let's say 0.7) predict it as unbiased and otherwise as biased?
Or do I explicitly need to have unbiased articles in my dataset and one neuron would be biased articles and the other unbiased?

Comment: you have a dataset of only one class, and you are expecting the NN to learn what is "non biased"?... if you take a child and you show him 1000 images where there are  apples and other fruit, can you expect that he knows what is an apple and what is a banana?

Comment: if the target of the NN in the dataset is always 1, the NN will just set the weights to 0 (as if they were uncorrelated) and use the bias to always predict 1